# Make the textfiled swipe up when keyboard is used swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, xcode11, swift5

I'm trying to make the text field `txtAdd` swipe up when the keyboard shows up, but I'm not really sure how to do it.

This is the code for adding items to the list:

```
@IBAction func submitBntFunc(_ sender: Any) {
    if let text = txtAdd.text{
             if text == ""{
                 return
             }
             txtAdd.text = ""
             txtAdd.resignFirstResponder()
        return txtField.text.append("\(text) \n")

         }

}
```

I tried with the code below but it didn't really work.

```
guard let keyboardSize = userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue else {return}
```

Answer (score 0):

try with this code

```
var originButton : CGFloat?

override func viewDidLoad()
{
     originButton = self.YOURBUTTON.frame.origin.y
     NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
     NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)

}

@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboard = ((notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue) {
        if self.view.frame.origin.y == 0 {
            self.YOURBUTTON.frame.origin.y -= keyboard.height

        }
    }
}

@objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    if self.YOURBUTTON.frame.origin.y != originButton {
        self.YOURBUTTON.frame.origin.y = originButton!
    }
}
```

Comment: it seems like its only the button that swipes up and not the "txtAdd" filed...

Comment: I added this line ` self.txtAdd.frame.origin.y -= keyboard.height ` but then it swipes up all the way to the top

Comment: And the txtAdd keeps swiping up every time that I click on the screen

Comment: are you using constrains? add this line ´self.view.layoutIfNeeded()´

Answer (score 0):

add this Observer in your viewDidLoad methods:=

```
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboard), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboard), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillChangeFrameNotification, object: nil)
```

And it is call this function:=

```
    @objc func keyboard(notification: Notification){
    let userInfo = notification.userInfo!
    let keyboardScreenEndFrame = (userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
    let keyboardViewEndFrame = view.convert(keyboardScreenEndFrame, to: view.window)

    if notification.name == UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification{
        //add your constrain here when keyboard is hiden
        self.scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
    }else{
        //add your constrain here when keyboard is visible
        self.scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: keyboardViewEndFrame.height, right: 0)
    }
    scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = scrollView.contentInset
}
```